# NullPointerException might be thrown as 'value' is nullable here sonar warning

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a code like this and when I am running it under sonar, it always complain on this line `value.contains("true")`

```
String value = getValue("/data/" + set, property);
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
  if (value.contains("true")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Here is the message it is giving me: `NullPointerException might be thrown as 'value' is nullable here`

I am already checking value for null check just above then why it is complaining inside? Am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**

After Andy's suggestion. I rewrote something like this:

```
String value = getValue("/data/" + set, property);
if (value!=null) {
  return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
}
return false;
```

Comment: you're fine. Use your judgement.

Comment: If you're using `Boolean.parseBoolean`, you don't even need the null check. `parseBoolean` returns `false` for a null input.

Comment: Boolean.parseBoolean will not work. It expects the value to be true (ignoring case) but in your original code, value was *containing* true. if value is exactly true then even a null check is not needed. You can simply do "true".equalsIgnoreCase(value)

Comment: I will ignore that and use what you have in your answer @AndyTurner or I will change my code accordingly.

Comment: SonarJava should be perfectly able to understand `isNullOrEmpty`. Can you please specify the fully qualified name of the method and the version of the library (if any)? And the version of SonarJava analyzer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that sonar doesn't understand the semantics of `Strings.isNullOrEmpty`.

You can make it less confusing all round if you were to write the condition as:

```
if (value != null) {
```

It doesn't really matter if you call `contains` on an empty string.

Also, this:

```
  if (value.contains("true")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

is more easily written as

```
  return value.contains("true");
```

Overall, you can write this as:

```
return value != null && value.contains("true");
```

---

Edit for your update: if you're using `Boolean.parseBoolean`, you don't even need the null check. `parseBoolean` returns `false` for a null input.

```
String value = getValue("/data/" + set, property);
return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
```

Comment: got it. thanks for fixing my stupid if else statements.